# Angular 4 Tag Lib

Tags: angular, jsp

I'm trying to use the JSP taglib throughout my application to do i18n, it is required that i18n is done using this approach. Is it possible to use this along with angular 2 or 4.

Comment: This is kind of broad. How do you plan on using Angular in this context? Can you give examples.

Comment: I'm trying to use JSP tags to tag the html.  So when the web page loads, an html element will be given the html tag, an example would be <tag>word</tag>. The tag will be taken and converted to the corresponding value in the java layer with values taken from a db.